# Is this notation for the set of limit points a standard notation?

Tags: general-topology, notation

Well, this doubt is probably silly. We have a standard notation for closure of a set $E$, we denote it $\bar{E}$ or $\operatorname{cl}{E}$ and we have a notation for the interior of a set $E$ we denote it $E^\circ$ or $\operatorname{int}{E}$. Now, what about the set of limit points of the set $E$? Is there a standard notation for it? Rudin's Analysis book denotes it like $E'$, so that  $\bar{E}=E\cup E'$, but is this notation a standard one?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: No that notation isn't standard.  If you were to use it, you would need to specify exactly what $E^\prime$ means.  For instance, that notation is sometimes used as the complement of a set.

Comment: It's fairly standard, but you should probably define the notation before using it. In the first few decades of the 20th century this notation was a lot more common than it is now, mainly, I suspect, because the notion of the derived set of a set had a much higher relative appearance in the literature than it has now.

Comment: Wikipedia: [Derived set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_set_%28mathematics%29)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$E'$ is used quite frequently to denote the set of limit points of a set $E$, and that is the notation used, as you have found, by Rudin.

I don't know that there is any *standard, universally* adopted notation for the set of limit points of a set; but the important thing is to always be clear about how any given author (including yourself) is defining what his/her notation is intended to represent.

Answer (score 0):

George F. Simmons' introduction to topology and modern analysis book denotes it like $D(A)$. I also prefer this notation.