# Alternative proof that the union of $A$ and $A'$ is closed for any set $A$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I want to see, if this alternative proof that $A \cup A'$ is closed for any set $A$ is correct. Standard references I checked after doing this problem contained a completely different proof, so I am not sure if what I have done is correct.

$A'$ here denotes the set of limit points of $A$.

Prove: $A \cup A'$ is closed for any set $A$.

Proof: Let $p$ be a limit point of $A \cup A'$. The result is proved if we show that $p$ is an element of $A \cup A'$. Since $p$ is a limit point of $A \cup A'$, $p$ is a limit point of $A$ or $p$ is a limit point of $A'$. If $p$ is a limit point of $A'$, then $p$ is an element of $A'$ (since $A'$ is closed) and so $p$ is an element of $A \cup A'$. If $p$ is a limit point of $A$, then by definition, $p$ is an element of $A'$ and so $p$ is an element of $A \cup A'$. Therefore $A \cup A'$ contains each of its accumulation points and hence is closed.

Comment: What is $A'$? ${}$

Comment: It is the set of limit points of $A$, as in the second line of the question.

Comment: @AlgTop: The notation clarification was added after my comment.

Comment: @copper.hat AFAIK the notation $A'$ is standard in general topology.

Comment: @Xam: It is common, but not standard. Better to be clear for such things. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/447617/27978.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conclusion that $p$ is a limit point of $A \cup A'$ implies that $p$ is a limit point of $A$ or a limit point of $A'$ is not justified.

You are basically using the fact that $(A \cup A')' \subseteq A \cup A'$, which is equivalent to the statement that $A \cup A'$ is closed, without any proof.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is correct, but somewhat overly complicated. It's easy to see that $A\subseteq A'$ (consider constant sequences), so $A\cup A'=A'$ and you use in your proof that that is closed.

Comment: Take $A = \{0\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. $0$ is in $A$ but it is not a limit point of $A$. The usual definition of a limit point $x \in A'$ is $(U \setminus \{x\}) \cap A \ne \emptyset$ for every open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$.